# MSBuild Exec task fails with Unicode filenames?

Tags: msbuild

I'm using `MSBuild`, `FLAC` and `LAME` to manage my MP3 collection, but it fails when it encounters a file with a non-ASCII character in the filename.

The following, cut down, project file shows the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Default">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <FLAC>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Flac\bin\flac.exe"</FLAC>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Decode
      Include="D:\Music\Artists\Kruder Dorfmeister\The K&amp;D Sessions\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Default" Inputs="@(Decode)" Outputs="%(Identity).always">
    <Exec Command="$(FLAC) --decode &quot;@(Decode)&quot;" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

When this gets to `"D:\Music\Artists\Kruder Dorfmeister\The K&D Sessions\Part One\02 - Jazz Master (K&D Session™).flac"`, it fails with the following error message:

```
Default:
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Flac\bin\flac.exe" --decode "D:\Music\Artists\Kruder Dorfmeister\The K&D Sessions\Part One\02
   - Jazz Master (K&D SessionT).flac"

  02 - Jazz Master (K&D SessionT).flac: ERROR initializing decoder
  init status = FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_INIT_STATUS_ERROR_OPENING_FILE

  An error occurred opening the input file; it is likely that it does not exist
  or is not readable.
```

As you can see, something is munging the "**™**" and converting it to "**T**".

But what? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in MSBuild `Exec` task writes the given command to a batch file and then runs it with `cmd /c /q`. Unfortunately, it writes the batch file with the **OEM code page**.

This means that Unicode filenames are mangled.

You'll have to write your own `Exec` (or `Pipe`, or even `ConvertMusic`) task instead.